# Error 582 while trying to access Windows Features

Tags: windows-10, dism

Today went to turn on the Hyper-V feature in the "Turn Windows Features On and Off" settings, but the dialogue would always just load for like 20 seconds then crash my machine.

I looked up alternative ways to view/access the Windows Features and found you could do it from DISM or Powershell. I attempted both commands to view the Windows Features:

`dism /online /get-features`

and

`get-windowsoptionalfeature -online`

and in both cases I get back this error:

```
Error: 582

An illegal character was encountered. For a multi-byte character set this 
includes a lead byte without a succeeding trail byte. For the Unicode character 
set this includes the characters 0xFFFF and 0xFFFE.
```

After looking at the dism logs and CBS logs:

dism.log

```
2018-05-07 23:54:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Processing the top level command token(get-features). - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::Private_ValidateCmdLine
2018-05-07 23:54:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Attempting to route to appropriate command handler. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2018-05-07 23:54:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Routing the command... - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2018-05-07 23:54:00, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Feature LegacyComponents with CBS state 4(CbsInstallStateStaged) being mapped to dism state 4(DISM_INSTALL_STATE_STAGED) - CDISMPackageFeature::LogInstallStateMapping
2018-05-07 23:54:07, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Failed to get the State of the Feature - CDISMPackageFeature::Internal_GetCbsState(hr:0x80070246)
2018-05-07 23:54:07, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Failed to get the CBS State of the Feature - CDISMPackageFeature::get_State(hr:0x80070246)
2018-05-07 23:54:07, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Failed to get the feature state. - CCBSFormatter::PrintCbsFeatures_ListFormat(hr:0x80070246)
2018-05-07 23:54:07, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Failed while processing command get-features. - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine(hr:0x80070246)
2018-05-07 23:54:07, Info                  DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=17208 TID=18628 Further logs for online package and feature related operations can be found at %WINDIR%\logs\CBS\cbs.log - CPackageManagerCLIHandler::ExecuteCmdLine
2018-05-07 23:54:07, Error                 DISM   DISM.EXE: DISM Package Manager processed the command line but failed. HRESULT=80070246
```

CBS.log

```
2018-05-07 23:54:07, Error                 CSI    00000003@2018/5/8:06:54:07.362 (F) onecore\base\lstring\lblob.cpp(2145): Error STATUS_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER originated in function RtlTranscodeLBlobs expression: __rv.UcsCharacter != (0xffffffff)
```

I clearly have some corrupted value wherever these command are attempting to read from. I'm just not sure if thats a registery value or something else and have no idea how I would go about fixing this without completely re-imaging my machine.

Any help is appreciated

UPDATE:

System Information

Win10 Pro
Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299
x64

Comment: It appears there is something massively incorrect with regard to your system image.  What build of Windows 10 are you using?  What edition of Windows 10 are you using?  What language packs are installed?  What keyboard layouts are installed?  This vital information should be added to your question in order to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Updated my system info. I have not installed any additional language packs or keyboard layouts.

Comment: I also get this problem with Win 10 Home  build 1803 , and `sfc /scannow` reports `Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service`, and Windows Update hangs the system after trying to update for a while